# Matrix Identity Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ and $C$ be $3 \times 2$ matrices and let $B$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix such that $AB=C$. Prove that:

$$||A_1 \times A_2 || \cdot |\det B| = ||C_1 \times C_2 ||$$

where $A_i$ and $C_i$ are the $i$th columns of $A$ and $C$.

Comment: So it is the cross product inside the norms?

Answer (score 3):

Write $A_n=(a_{1n},a_{2n},a_{3n})$, $C_k=(c_{1n},c_{2n},c_{3n})$ and recall
$$
A_1\times A_2= \left|\matrix{i&j&k\\ a_{11}&a_{21}&a_{31}\\a_{12}&a_{22}&a_{32}} \right|= \left|\matrix{i&a_{11}&a_{12}\\ j&a_{21}&a_{22}\\k&a_{31}&a_{32}} \right|.
$$

Now observe that
$$
\left( \matrix{i&a_{11}&a_{12}\\ j&a_{21}&a_{22}\\k&a_{31}&a_{32}}\right)\cdot \left(\matrix{1&0\\0&B }\right)=\left( \matrix{i&c_{11}&c_{12}\\ j&c_{21}&c_{22}\\k&c_{31}&c_{32}}\right)$$
follows from the assumption $AB=C$.

Now take the determinant and use its multiplicity to get
$$\det\left( \matrix{i&a_{11}&a_{12}\\ j&a_{21}&a_{22}\\k&a_{31}&a_{32}}\right)\det \left(\matrix{1&0\\0&B }\right)=\det\left( \matrix{i&c_{11}&c_{12}\\ j&c_{21}&c_{22}\\k&c_{31}&c_{32}}\right).
$$

Thus we have

> $$
> (A_1\times A_2)\det B=C_1\times C_2.
> $$

Finally, take the norm to obtain the desired formula.

Comment: @copper.hat If you undelete your answer, I will happily upvote it. It is actually significantly different.

Comment: Thank Julien. Its not really that different, the $i,j,j$ basically turn the determinant into a linear functional.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, but my answer is only about computations, while yours is slightly more theoretical. So +1.

Comment: Thanks! I was never comfortable with the $i,j,k$ stuff until I made  the inner product/determinant connection.

Comment: @copper.hat Interestingly, I had never seen this i,j,k determinant formula before teaching in the US. I first disliked it. Now I admit I like it.

Comment: I learned it in physics & electrical engineering during my undergrad in Ireland. I like shortcuts when I understand the underpinnings, but it has only been in the recent past that I have had time to fill in some gaps!

Answer (score 3):

This is the same answer as Julien's above, with the $i,j,k$ replaced by a linear functional equivalent.

The cross product $x \times y$ can be defined as the unique vector that satisfies $\langle z, x \times y \rangle = \det \begin{bmatrix} x & y & z\end{bmatrix}$.

If $z$ is an arbitrary vector, then $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2  & z\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A  & z\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} Ab_1 & A b_2  & z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 & c_2  & z\end{bmatrix}$.

This gives $\langle z, c_1 \times c_2 \rangle = \det \begin{bmatrix} c_1 & c_2 & z\end{bmatrix} = \det \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2  & z\end{bmatrix} \det \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} =  \langle z, (\det B)(a_1 \times a_2) \rangle$.

Uniqueness gives the desired result.

Comment: Deleting not because it is wrong, but because it is basically identical to Julien's answer (and I am too slow typing!).